# Принцип generic типов Java

Tags: java, generics

Пытаюсь написать параметризуемый метод, принимающий параметризованные типы:

```java
    public static <T> void findMinMax(
                Stream<? extends T> stream,
                Comparator<? super T> comparator,
                BiConsumer<? super T, ? super T> minMaxConsumer
        ) {
            Stream<T> sortedStream = stream.sorted(comparator);
    }
```

Объявление метода имею из [условия задачи](https://stepik.org/lesson/12781/step/12?unit=3128).
Непонятны две вещи:

1. Не понимаю почему `stream` может параметризоваться  любым подтипом `T`, а `comparator` любым родительским типом `T`. То есть почему у `stream` тип `Stream<? extends T>`, а у `comparator` - `Comparator<? super T>`? С какой целью это сделано?
2. В данный момент при компиляции вылетает ошибка:

```java
error: incompatible types: Stream<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Stream<T>
        Stream<T> sortedStream = stream.sorted(comparator);
                                                  ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>findMinMax(Stream<? extends T>,Comparator<? super T>,BiConsumer<? super T,? super T>)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends T from capture of ? extends T
```

Не могу понять, что не так. Ведь `T` является и своим подтипом и своим супер-типом. Почему тогда компилятор говорит о несовместимости типов? Что компилятор подразумевает под `CAP#1`?

Comment: `Stream<? extends T> sorted = stream.sorted(comparator)` вроде должно быть так.

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Но не совсем понятно. Ведь, когда мы пишем тип перед переменной - мы присваиваем ей какой-то конкретный тип, а не "какой-то неизвестный" подтип или супер-тип `T`. А у вас получается, что при объявлении переменной ей присваивается какой-то неопределённый тип(подтип `T`)

Comment: ошибка потому что в начале вы объявляете его так: `Stream<? extends T> stream`, а далее после сортировки вы меняете его тип. Говоря что он точно вот такой: `Stream<T> sortedStream` по этому у вас и ломается, попробуйте параметры метода изменить, и у вас будет работать с вашими данными.

Comment: Почему я не могу положить в переменную, имеющую тип `T`, объект подтипа `T`? Я ведь могу, например, записать`Integer` в `Object` переменную. Тогда в чём тут проблема?

Comment: это уже другой вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Generics (Обобщенные типы) инвариантны, то есть нельзя присвоить к `Stream<Number>` ссылку на `Stream<Double>`. Wildcard (Маска) придает свойство вариантности при взаимодействии с обобщенными типами рассматривая их либо как источники объектов Т (Producer Extends, см. PECS), либо как приёмники Т (Consumer Super, см. PECS).

Wildcard это не Generic, это специальный тип параметризации, его можно использовать только при декларировании переменных или аргументов методов, все Wildcard содержат вопросительный знак - `?`.

Инвариантный Generic (Обобщенный тип):

`List<T>` - List принимает T и его наследников, и возвращает объекты Т.

**Ковариантность** достигается через Upper Bounded Wildcards `? extends T`:

`List<? extends T>` - List **возвращает объекты Т**, так как содержит объекты Т либо наследников Т:

```
List<? extends Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Double>() {{ add(2.5); }};
Number n = numbers.get(0);
```

**Контравариантность** достигается через Lower Bounded Wildcards `? super T`:

`List<? super T>` - List **принимает объекты T** и его наследников:

```
List<? super Number> objects = new ArrayList<Object>() {{ add(2.5); add("it's fine!"); }}
objects.add((short) 256);
```

Этот wildcard указывает, что исходный List может содержать что угодно, вплоть до Object, по этой причине метод `get(n)` вернет Object, но wildcard позволит передать в List объекты с типом Number и его наследников.

---

Разбор ошибки:

```
public static <T> void findMinMax(Stream<? extends T> stream) {
    Stream<T> sortedStream = stream.sorted(comparator);
}
```

Ошибка из-за попытки присвоить Upper Bounded Wildcards к типу Stream.

Почему так сделать нельзя:

```java
List<? extends Number> containsNumbers = new ArrayList<Double>();

containsNumbers.add(new Integer(100)); // Ошибка, wildcard `? extends Number` позволяет только прочитать объекты типа `Number`.

List<Number> numbers = containsNumbers // Ошибка, нельзя присвоить List<? extends Number>
numbers.add(new Integer(200)); // если бы не ошибка выше, то можно было бы добавить объект неподходящего типа
```

Comment: Не совсем понял. Выражение `<? extends T` означает, что экземпляр класса, который данным выражением параметризован, возвращает объекты `T` типа, а  выражение`<? super T>`, что принимает объекты `T` типа? Или `<? extends T>` означает, что класс может параметризоваться подтипом `T`, и соответственно `<? super T>` означает, что класс может параметризоваться супер-типом `T`?

Comment: @FedotSoldier Я старался, но видно мой ответ не очень.

Я тебе лучше ссылок накидаю.
На русском, там больше про Kotlin но там рассказано и про java: https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/generics.html

На английском:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html

Даже если с английским не очень просто посмотри примеры кода и попробуй повторить.

Comment: @FedotSoldier перечитал твой вопрос, первый вариант правильный, второй нет, `что класс может параметризовать супер-типом T` вот это неправильно. Вся эта путаница из-за плохого выборка ключевых слов в java для wildcard'ов, в других языках для декларирования вариативности используют `<out T>` вместо `<? extends T>` и `<in T>` вместо `<? super T>`.

Comment: Теперь уже теплее. По поводу "wildcard" стало понятнее. Спасибо за старания, в ближайшее время почитаю ваши ссылки