# Не понимаю по какому принципу создается лист параметризованный WildCard

Tags: java, generics, wildcards

Необходимо создать лист, принимающий на вход только объекты, наследующиеся от другого класса.
В данном примере лист Vehicles, который должен принимать на вход объекты класса Car и Bicycle.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<? extends Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
        vehicles.add(new Car()); // Ошибка компиляции
        vehicles.add(new Bicycle());
    }
}

class Vehicle{}
class Car extends Vehicle{}
class Bicycle extends Vehicle{}
```

При этом возникает ошибка компиляции, вариант же с <? super Vehicle> работает как требуется:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<? super Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
        vehicles.add(new Car());
        vehicles.add(new Bicycle());
    }
```

Разве в данном коде лист не должен принимать классы стоящие выше по иерархии наследования? То есть, например, чтобы запись <? super Car> принимала бы объект класса vehicle, который стоит выше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда переменная-список объявлена с использованием вайлд-карда с верхней границей `? extends Vehicle`, это значит, что список *будет **возвращать*** объекты типа `Vehicle`, т.е. самого класса или его наследников.  Значит, работать будут методы *чтения* данных из такого списка `List::get` (Provider Extends в [принципе PECS](https://habr.com/ru/articles/559268/)).  При помощи метода `add` в такой список можно будет добавить только `null` значения.

Однако, инициализировать такой список всё же можно несколькими способами:

- через конструктор, в который будет передана коллекция:

```java
List<? extends Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Car(), new Bicycle()));
Vehicle v = vehicles.get(0);
Bicycle b = (Bicycle) vehicles.get(1);
```

- при помощи статического метода `List.of` (Java 9+):

```java
List<? extends Vehicle> vehicles = List.of(new Car(), new Bicycle());
```

- при помощи инициализации с двойными скобками, где также будет создан промежуточный анонимный класс для списка:

```java
List<? extends Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>() {{
    add(new Car());  
    add(new Bicycle());
}};
```

---

Соответственно, если список определён как вайлдкард с нижней границей `<? super Vehicle>`, он будет *приёмником* (Consumer Super), то есть методы записи будут работать, а чтения -- уже нет.

```java
List<? super Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
vehicles.add(new Car()); // ok
vehicles.add(new Bicycle());

//Vehicle v = vehicles.get(0); // ошибка компиляции
Bicycle b = (Bicycle) vehicles.get(1); // а здесь всё хорошо :)
```

---

Похожий вопрос (апрель 2019): [Принцип generic типов Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/974479/)